# block program with iptables

Tags: firewall

I have two programs both of which are in Java.

Program A was written by me. If it wants to establish an external connection, I'm okay with this.

Program B was not written by me. If it wants to establish an external connection, I'm not okay with this.

How can I configure iptables to allow `java A` to make outgoing connections, but `java B` to be denied?

If iptables can't be used for this, what other options do I have?

Comment: Do the two programs use different ports, or do they use the same port? If they use the same port, iptables cannot (AFAIK) differentiate between the two programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the programs as different users you can use the `owner` module.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner javaauser -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner javabuser -j REJECT
```

Comment: Great idea!  Hadn't thought of that and side-steps the case where the dest port is the same.

Comment: Oh... oh wow. I like it, it definitely solves my problem. +1, +check. On a related note, is there a way to add logging to failed attempts? Assuming there is, would the explanation of how be short enough to fit in a comment, or should I make a new question? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Add `iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner javabuser -j LOG` before the `-j REJECT` line.

Answer (score 0):

You must block the port that the program you don't want external access uses. Suppose it uses port 30000:

```
 # iptables -A OUTPUT -s 0/0 -d 0/0 -p tcp --dport 30000 -j DROP
```

This is a simple rule, you can learn more on this [simple howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo). Depending on what distribution you use, you can also try [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor), a kernel level application firewall.

Comment: What if I won't know what ports it wants to use until it runs?

Comment: Then iptables may not be the right tool for the job.

Comment: Just match on owner.  This will disable that owner from connecting entirely.  This may be a problem if you use the UID for other things.  You may need to exempt some ports.  Check the log messages when the program runs to determine the ports and addresses it uses.